# I'm trying to draw using my Wacom tablet but why does the corner of my drawing have an extra stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to draw using my Wacom tablet but why does the corner of my drawing have an extra stroke?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This should be useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/AdobeIllustrator/comments/7e1a5p/why_do_i_get_these_weird_fat_strokes_am_i_working/dq3zfld?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Problem : Variation value of pressure**

it seems you have high variation value set on your brush's variation therefore double click on brush thumbnail to open your brush setting and change your variation of size to "0" it will remove any thickness changes and will draw like mouse and if you want to make pressurized lines then just simply reduce it :)

[image]